# How to rbind new rows to a data table at certain time intervals in Shiny dashboard?

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a shiny app with 2 outputs `datatableoutput` and `plotoutput`.I have 2 variables `st` and `et` in a data frame which will be initialized to a value, i need to add new rows to the existing data frame which has the following logic
    1. New `st` value is previous value of `et`.
    2. New `et` value is previous value of `st - 1000`.
    3. New value of`st` and `et` should be added as new row in my dataframe after 
       every 5 seconds.
 Based on newly added rows the line graph should get updated.

Below are my ui.r and server.r codes,currently i am able to create new values of `st` and `et` according to the logic but failed to add new rows and plot the graph

Ui.r

```
 library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

 titlePanel("Incremental Plots"),

 sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(),

   mainPanel(
      tableOutput('var')
    )
  )
))
```

Server.r

```
library(shiny)
start_time <- 100000
end_time <- start_time - 1000
shinyServer(function(input,output,session){
   omega <- reactive({
    invalidateLater(1000, session)

   #dataf <<- data.frame(st = c(start_time),et = c(end_time))
   return(dataf)
   })

  # update non reactive value
   observe({
    omega()
    start_time <<- end_time
    end_time <<- start_time - 1000
    dataf <<- data.frame(st = start_time,et = end_time)


  })

  output$var <- renderTable(omega())
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a combination of [`reactiveVal`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.2/reactiveVal.html) and `observe` for that. Note that you can call the value of a `reactiveVal` named `x` with `x()`, and you can set its value to `y` by doing `x(y)`. A working example is given below, hope this helps!

---

[image]

---

```
library(shiny)

ui<- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Incremental Plots"),      
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),        
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput('var')
    )
  )
))

start_time <- 100000
end_time = start_time - 1000

server<- function(input,output,session){

  # Initialize
  reval_omega <- reactiveVal(data.frame(st = c(start_time),et = c(end_time)))
  reval_start <- reactiveVal(start_time)
  reval_end <- reactiveVal(end_time)

  # update our reactiveVal 
  observe({
    invalidateLater(1000, session) # every second
    isolate({
      reval_start(reval_end()) # set start time to current end time
      reval_end(reval_start() - 1000) # set end time to start - 1000
      omega_new <- data.frame(st = reval_start(),et = reval_end()) # create a new row for the dataframe
      reval_omega(rbind(reval_omega(),omega_new)) # rbind the reval_omega() and the new row, and store result in reval_omega()
    })
  })
  output$var <- renderTable(reval_omega())
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Great, glad I could help! :)