# Time Condition ObserveEvent/Reactive Shiny

Tags: r, time, datatable, shiny

(first question today, hope it will be successful)

I am currently developing a shiny app and I would like to automatically create a dataTable dependent on time. For example, to add a row every second. Up until now, I succeeded on adding a row thanks to a action button (every time I click on it, it adds a row) but I can't find a way to automate the process... Has anyone have an idea ?

Here is my code below : I am using a proxy to edit my dataTable in real time

```
observeEvent(???, {
  proxy %>% addRow(
    data.frame(input$add,
               date = toString(Sys.time()), 
               Country = sample(countries.list,1),
               Value = round(runif(1,0,1000)))
  )})
```

Maybe I am wrong using an observe event, I am open to any advices :)

Thanks a lot

Comment: check `invalidatelater` https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.5/invalidateLater.html

Comment: Yes thanks, I find something similar --> ReactiveTimer ! Super Useful! Thanks you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rbind new rows to a data table output in Shiny dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50812251/how-to-rbind-new-rows-to-a-data-table-output-in-shiny-dashboard)